# laravel how to send pagination result into ajax request

Tags: ajax, laravel

in laravel make view in ajax call the page is not loaded properly.it loaded like below image.[image]

[image]

Comment: Pass the older pagination to the function then Debug the paginated collection with `dd()` then you can simulate pagination with skip and take functions. Remember to set new pagination array for this collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Eloquent Resource](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources)

1. Generate a resource class with this command:

   ```
   php artisan make:resource User
   ```

   **Note:** Use your own model name in place of `User`.
2. Then create a resource collection class with this command:

   ```
   php artisan make:resource UserCollection
   ```

   or

   ```
   php artisan make:resource Users --collection
   ```
3. return response to ajax like this:

   ```
   public function getUsers() {
       $users = User::paginate();

       /**
        * this will convert your collection into array and 
        * also sends the additional pagination information.
        */
       return new UserCollection($users);
       // or 
       // return new Users($users);
   }
   ```

Additionally you can manage/transform the response in `toArray()` in your resource like this:

```
class User extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        ];
    }
}
```